# Github + Jenkins >> How to trigger build on "Commit and Push" in code repository?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, githooks

- I have setup a local instance of Jenkins on my computer, and I can
  access it through - "http://localhost:8080".
- Created a Public Git repository, and added my ASP.NET MVC
  project there.
- Also configured Jenkins to build the project, and it does the job
  very well.

However, this is a manual trigger. I mean, the build gets triggered only when a user clicks on "Build Now" in Jenkins console.

Actually, my requirement is to trigger a build when the changes are committed and pushed. (that means, "Commit and Push" while checking-in changes).

I referred to a lot of blogs and posts, and came to know about Git hooks. I also tried creating "post-receive" hook. I created a hook at the location where source code is mapped (For example, "E:\Git\test-jenkins.git\hooks").

```
#!/bin/bash
curl POST "http://localhost:8080/job/Test-Jenkins/build" --data delay=0sec
```

But this doesn't work. A build is never getting triggered on "Commit and Push". when I try copying the URL directly in the browser, it triggers a build, so I believe there is no issue with the URL. But the script itself is not getting executed.

Could anyone please suggest how to solve this problem?

Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Github` server will not be able to reach the `Jenkins` server hosted on local, to trigger the build.

You will either need a `static IP address` or you need to map a `DNS` entry to your dynamic IP. Also, you need to open the port `8080` for external access. Only then `GitHub` will be able to reach your local instance with its webhook.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Refer to step # 8 of the article >> http://www.frictionlesscode.com/have-continuous-integration-with-jenkins-in-30-mins/ Here, the author has used localhost only (no IP address) while configuring post-receive git hook. I believe this should work on localhost - because, git hook is on local computer from where localhost is very much accessible. Do you think this is still because of localhost only?

Comment: For future readers, the article @Nirman linked in his comment, above, described running Jenkins on a PC with a local git repository configured with post commit hook - so the article author didn't need an externally accessible IP address - he wasn't using GitHub.

Comment: @marfarma: you are right and in OP case as he is using Github he needs to have jenkins hosted on public ip.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use "webhook & services" in your repository settings in Github. Please see the image below:[image: jenkins + github]

To implement it, you have to have a public domain for your Jenkins